# How to handle ObjectId in Javascript, Can't parse it

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, mongodb

I am having an issue when read JSON returned from my ASP.NET webservice to the client. The JSON returned contains an `ObjectId` generated in MongoDB database, and I need it in the client.

The problem start when I run

```
 var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d)[0]; // array of companies
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token O
```

I assume is that the Javascipt JSON parser doesn't recognize the `ObjectId`.

In my .NET C# code I seralized and return JSON:

```
 var jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict };
return results.ToJson(jsonWriterSettings);
```

The return JSON string from the webservice:

```
[{ "companies" : [{ "id" : ObjectId("53e129ed0000000000000000"), "name" :
 "Company 1" }, { "id" : ObjectId("53e12a290000000000000000"), "name" :
 "Company 2" }, { "id" : ObjectId("53e12a650000000000000000"), "name" :
 "Company 3" }] }]"
```

How can I use the ObjectId in Javascript. I do need the string of the ObjectId in some of the HTML elements (e.g. drop down list values)?

Update: I found out about the [BSON seralizer here](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson). However, I don't know if that's the appropriate solution.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the raw JSON code you receive from your webservice?

Comment: @Philipp, Hi, I've added it to the question body. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would usually not recommended to expose an ObjectId to the user, because a 24-digit hex string is not very user-friendly. But when you still want to do this, you should be able to convert it to a string with its [toString](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/) method.

The JSON example code you posted is not valid JSON, so it's no miracle that parsing on the client-side fails. That means you need to find a different tool (or maybe you are just not using it properly) to generate your JSON or convert the ObjectId's to strings before converting it.

Comment: Do you recommend that I just use a integer which I auto increment myself? (those lists are short, max 50 items)

Comment: @IdanShechter In order to provide useful UI design advise I would need a more complete view of your whole user interface.

Comment: The list like the company list will be used to populate a drop down list, that's all, and I have a few of those. If I use int as the Id, I can query the document to the amount of items and add +1 to the next item. The insertion of new data will only be available for the admin, only I can add new companies, so it shouldn't be intensive on the database, especially if it's a short list and happens once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your web services so it returns:

```
[{ "companies" : [{ "id" : "53e129ed0000000000000000", "name" :
 "Company 1" }, { "id" : "53e12a290000000000000000", "name" :
 "Company 2" }, { "id" : "53e12a650000000000000000", "name" :
 "Company 3" }] }]"
```

Otherwise it is invalid JSON

Answer (score -1):

```
var userid=results[i].id;
```

Get objectId Value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.